# having a jQuery issue with getting a toggle effect

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to get a toggle effect where the button slides left to right. When you click the tab button the box will slide out(to the left), then click it again and it will slide back in (to the right). I have tried a few different ways to do this but nothing seems to be working for me.

You can check everything out at: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bcreed33/h2gug2zd/

here is what I have so far in jQuery

```
 $(function () {
         $('#tab').click(
         function () { $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 500); })
    });
```

Now if I run something like this... the box will just slide out then right back in...

```
   $(function () {
         $('#tab').click(
         function () { $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 500); }),
       $('#tab').click(
         function () { $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': '-362px' }, 500); })

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's click function only accepts one callback, you have to take care of the  toggle functionality yourself.

```
$(function () {
     $('#tab').click(function () { 
         var flag = $(this).data('flag');

         $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': (flag ? -362 : 0) + 'px' }, 500);

         $(this).data('flag', ! flag)
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2gug2zd/3/)

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works:

```
$(function () {
     $('#tab').click(
         if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
             $(this).removeClass('selected');
             $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': '-362px' }, 500);
         }else{
             $(this).addClass('selected')
             $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': '0px' }, 500);
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to keep track of the toggle yourself. What you can do is change the variable that keeps track of the toggled state after the animation is done using the callback on the jquery `.animate` function, which is called after the animation is completed. By calculating the width of the side box content dynamically (stored in `sideBoxContentWidth`), if you decide to change it or make it a relative size using a percentage measurement, the toggle will adapt to the new width. The code is below--hope this helps!

**EDIT:** [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/rcm0z0th/) a link to a fiddle with a working example.

```
$(function () {
     var toggledOut = false,
         sideBoxContentWidth = $('#sideBoxContent').width();

     $('#tab').click(function () {
         var leftOffset = toggledOut ? '-' + sideBoxContentWidth : '0';

         $('#sideBox').animate({ 'left': leftOffset + 'px' }, 500, function() {
             toggledOut = !toggledOut;
         });
     });
});
```